# jQuery animation function breaks when switching tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-animate

**UPDATE:** I reproduced the error in a plunkr: See http://plnkr.co/BpYfCNBESUT6ZkiSZHgx

The problem occurs when you do following:

Open [website](http://satest.solvisoft.nl/). Refresh website, while you see the page is loading in the browser tab, `when you see the spinner in the tab`.

[image]
Switch to another tab in your browser. If it doens't happen. Try again. If did as said, you are most likely seeing this:

[image]

You might say, `this is not such a big deal, you have to be real fast to let this error happen`. However, imagine somebody with a slow connection, he goes to another tab in his browser, continue watching his youtube video, while website is loading. When he comes back he just sees the page keeps loading.

---

Lets say ive this `animation` code:

```
$pageloaderbar.animate({
    width: "46%"
}, {
    duration: 700,
    complete: function () {
        $scope.continue();
    }
});
```

When the first `animation` completes it calls an new function, called `$scope.continue();`. Which looks likes this:

```
$scope.continue = function () {
    $timeout(function () {
        $pageloaderbar.animate({
            width: "100%"
        }, {
            duration: 500,
            complete: function () {
                $scope.PageIsLoading = false;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The problem is, when a user switches tab in his browser, between the `$pageloaderbar.animate` and the `$scope.continue`, the `$plageloaderbar.animate` function never reaches the `complete` function. The browser console shows the following error (Chrome)

[image]

My question is, how can i see if the user is `active` on the website? Or, how can i still execute the function, even if the user is not `active` on the `browser tab`?

**Because there seems no one with an awnser, i have figured an little workaround myself. However, if someone still can explain why the `animation` breaks when switching tab, im very pleased.**

The workaround was quite simple, i only had to add this code.

```
complete: function () {
    if(document.hidden) {
        $(window).on("blur focus", function () {
            $scope.continue();
        });
    } else {
        $scope.continue();
    }
}
```

instead of:

```
complete: function () {
    $scope.continue();
}
```

Comment: can you reproduce this in a plunker/fiddle?

Comment: Im sorry, in an snippet it works just fine. I also cant show an demo cause its on a local dev envoirment.

Comment: What is $scope and why isn't it defined when the current tab has focus? Have you traced it at all? What is going on in the life cycle of $scope? We can't see a whole lot from what you've provided but this shouldn't be reacting this way. Console.log($scope) at various points and see what you find.

Comment: Can you add relevant code here. I think `$scope.continue` is overridden. Possibly by boolean `$scope.continue = false;`. That's why when you call `$scope.continue()`, it throws error `... is not a function`.

Comment: @trevster344 `$scope` is from `angular` if you are intrested, here is the whole code. Maybe it helps you: https://jsfiddle.net/3kc32zf3/

Comment: @Tushar see this link for the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/3kc32zf3/

Comment: I think its an problem or bug within `angular`. Without `angular` the animation just continues in the background. And when the user comes back, the animation is complete. Im going to try to setup a website with the error. So you guys can see it, it would help alot i think.

Comment: What does your controller declaration look like? Is it global? what version of angular are you on?

Comment: You can see the controller in the source code i added, the version of angular we're using is v1.5.8

Comment: Unable to make the problem occur with that solution in there but it's good that you found a solution. I don't agree with the solution personally but as long as it gets the job done. Take care.

Comment: Yeah, `document.hidden` is not a totally good solution. I have to at the moment. No one seems to have an anwser to this :(

Comment: It should be possible to reproduce issue at plnkr http://plnkr.co

Comment: @guest271314 i finaly managed to reproduce the error in a plunker: http://plnkr.co/BpYfCNBESUT6ZkiSZHgx

Comment: @tanmay i created a plunker. See http://plnkr.co/BpYfCNBESUT6ZkiSZHgx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is being caused by the jQuery `animate` function, which passes the animate options object to a function called `speed`. This function checks to see if the `document` is `hidden` - which it will be if the tab is inactive. If it is hidden, (or `fx.off` is set to `true`), all animation durations are set to `0`.

You can see this on line `7137` in your plunkr's jQuery file.

```
    if ( jQuery.fx.off || document.hidden ) {
    opt.duration = 0;
```

As the animation now has no duration, it becomes synchronous, and so the fact that your `complete` function comes after the call to `animate`, is an issue.

To fix this, you would need to move the `complete` function declaration above your call to `animate`.

Comment: You deserve the bounty, you did really look into the code and figured it out. I checked it and it's true. It works when you place it above, and also that jquery breaks because it sets `opt.duration = 0`. Ñice work!

Answer (score 0):

In the newer version of chrome this is related to visibility of the tab and your function is breaking due to that. you can use visibility API to know that tab is visible to the user or not.

Please have a look at this link which i found :

http://dystroy.org/demos/vis-en.html

Comment: Well, if you read my question carefully, you can see that i actualy had to add that to make the code work. It has nothing to do with the visibility API. Just read the question, the problem is the `animation` function from the `jQuery` api, which breaks when switching tabs ..

Answer (score -1):

```
 $scope.continue = function () {
        $timeout(function () {
            $pageloaderbar.animate({
                width: "100%"
            }, {
                duration: 500,
                complete: function () {
                    $scope.PageIsLoading = false;

                    $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
                    $pageloaderwrap.addClass("page-loader-finished");

                    $scope.pageReady();
                }
            });
        });
    }

    var $pageloaderwrap = $(".page-loader-wrap");
    var $pageloader = $(".page-loader");
    var $pageloaderbar = $(".page-loader .page-loader-bar");

    $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");


    $pageloaderbar.animate({
        width: "46%"
    }, {
        duration: 700,
        complete: function () {
            if (document.hidden) {
                $(window).on("blur focus", function () {
                    $scope.continue();
                });
            } else {
                $scope.continue();
            }
        }
    });
```

Try to define your continue function before call $pageloaderbar.animate . That may not be the main problem but, it is always possible to have a issue because of that.

Your solution is just a patch, not a real solution and not seems good. Even if it solves your problem, you must find a certain way to prevent this error.

I strongly recommend you to leave jquery. Such problems usually comes from jquery - angular incompatibilities.

Comment: This is not an awnser. Post such things as an comment. Im aware that you can't post comments, due the reputation. Just remember to post awnsers, instead of tips and things like 'maybe its because of this'